# Remove duplicate two way linked rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have two columns like the following and I want to delete the duplicates.

```
Column1    Column2
1           10
2            9
3            8
4            7
5            6
6            5
7            4
8            3
9            2 
10           1
```

I want to delete half of these entries so that there are only 5 rows like this:

```
Column1    Column2
1           10
2            9
3            8
4            7
5            6
```

Any ideas? I know how I could do it in C# and remove if there are duplicates then delete but I want to do it in SQL. The values represent ID's and a relationship between the ID's. Order doesnt matter in the relationship so 1-10 is the same as 10-1. So in that way there are duplicate relationships.

Comment: `I want to do it in SQL.` Then why have you tagged your question `C#` ?

Comment: I don't see any duplicate rows. How is 1-10 the same as 10-1?

Comment: @ L. B. clicked C# by accident I have updated.

Comment: @gunr2171 I updated to explain what I mean by duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be as follows:

```
DELETE t FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.Column1 > t.Column2 AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM MyTable tt
    WHERE t.Column1=tt.Column2 AND t.Column2=tt.Column1
)
```

The `t.Column1 > t.Column2` says that if there is a pair of matching rows, delete the one where `Column1` is greater than `Column2`.

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c29da/1)